# Is there a way to uniquely identify email addresses, phones, etc. with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Trying to set up a 2-way sync with Graph contacts. When I receive a response from Graph for a specific contact I can't seem to find a way to uniquely identify the phone/email attributes.

In my use case, each email address and phone number are separate entities with a unique id identifying them. This solves for the edge case of having multiple addresses or numbers of the same type (i/e home, work, school, mobile).

In a perfect world, I would like to be able to send metadata along with each phone/email entity that uniquely identifies it on creation in Graph. That way when I set up a subscription or even query the contact, I can directly map the returned contact objects phone/email to our specific phone/email.

Is this possible? I know Google has ids that solve for this.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "contact"? There are several entries that either use that name or have similar properties.

Comment: By contact I am describing the resource `me/contacts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Outlook Contacts](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/contact) are structured a little differently than Google Contacts. Rather than having a single `gd:phoneNumber` property with distinct `rel` values, Outlook uses distinct phone number properties.

It's also important to keep in mind that some phone number properties are collections rather than single values (i.e. `homePhones`). These collections are ordered so these collections can be maps back to Outlook's UI pretty easily. For example, `homePhones[0]` holds the "Home Phone" value while `homePhones[1]` holes "Home Phone 2".

In terms of a 1:1 mapping:

- `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#home` == `homePhones[0]`
- `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#work` == `businessPhones[0]`
- `http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile` == `mobilePhone`

Finally, Microsoft Graph only returns a limited set of phone numbers by default. In my experience, the set returned by Graph is almost always sufficient but there are certainly some edge cases (the healthcare sector still makes use of pagers for example).

You can access these additional phone numbers using [Extended Properties](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/extended-properties-overview). This is done by requesting specifically requesting a given property using the MAPI tag name.

For example, if you need to retrieve the Pager property, you can request the MAPI identifier [`0x3A21`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagpagertelephonenumber-canonical-property) as an extended property:

```
/v1.0/me/contacts?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x3A21')
```

You can find the complete list of MAPI properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/mapi-properties).

Answer (score 0):

```
"homePhones": [],
"mobilePhone": "124124124124",
"businessPhones": [
     "+86 (510) 12114142"
],
"spouseName": null,
"personalNotes": "",
"children": [],
"emailAddresses": [
   {
   "name": "Charles Test(test@microsoft.com)",
   "address": "Test.Test@microsoft.com"
   }
],
"homeAddress": {},
"businessAddress": {
   "city": "Wuxi"
},
"otherAddress": {}
```

As you know, the phone reference is not unique, user can share same phone number, so it cannot be used as uniquely identify in all MS Authentication API, unless the phone reference is user's id. So it is not possible for your perfect world.

For the same reason, user can share the same address reference, so it is cannot be used as uniquely identify in all MS Authentication API.  So it is not possible for your perfect world too.

Comment: I would disagree with you on 'the phone is not unique'. The number may not be unique, but the phone entity is. Same goes for email address.

Comment: Phone itself and email address itself is unique, this is no doubt. But our case is not for this, we focus on their reference in the user. Many user may use the same phone or same email, so there are not unique for user. Do not forget your question background. I didn't talk the phone/email itself on my answer. Have add the "reference" to restrict the phone.